# Upgrade raspbian to jessie

Tags: debian, update, raspbian-jessie

The question has been asked [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27858/upgrade-to-raspbian-jessie). I have a raspberry pi 2, running Raspbian, I want to upgrade to Jessie. the answers say, change wheezy to jessie.

I don't know about debian, haven't run it on PC since 2 years ago or so, but I asked a friend who's a debian user, running jessie now, he doesn't know anything about raspberry pi, but he said don't change to jessie, change to main, which kinda make sense cause jessie is the current release, his `sources.list` looks like this

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.3.0 _stable_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20131215-03:40]/ stable main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.3.0 _stable_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20131215-03:40]/ stable main


# stable-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
#
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable contrib main non-free

deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import

deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib non-free

# proposed additions for a 7 point release
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie-proposed-updates main contrib non-free
```

I am asking this question just to know what to do, to change to jessie or to main?

Comment: @joan so you say I shouldn't use main? or should I? thats all i care about and it's not a dupe but who cares, i just want to know what to use, main or jessie

Comment: I'm telling you this is a duplicate question.  You have either misunderstood what your friend said or the advice given was nonsense.  The main keyword has absolutely nothing to do with the release version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now, Raspbian is behind Debian in upgrading the stable branch; on Debian it's jessie, on Raspbian it's still wheezy, and jessie is the testing branch.

If you want jessie, upgrade to it specifically.

The distribution is the same regardless of model (A, B, 2, etc.).