# Installing MongoDB On Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: software-compilation, mongodb

i have been trying for 2 days to get MongoDB installed on my raspberry pi but i am unable to get it to work.

i know that the official mongo isn't for for ARM, but there is a fork i found at:

```
https://github.com/skrabban/mongo-nonx86
```

but it fails top build. i have seen this repose referenced in several sites, but it doesn't seem to be working for me and i can figure out why it doesn't compile.

i followed the instructions on: `http://c-mobberley.com/wordpress/2013/10/14/raspberry-pi-mongodb-installation-the-working-guide/`

but i get a compilation error when running `scons`. the error i get is:

```
sudo scons .
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons version: 2.3.1
python version: 2 7 9 'final' 0
Checking whether the C++ compiler works... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file unistd.h... (cached) yes
Checking whether clock_gettime is declared... (cached) yes
Checking for C library rt... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file execinfo.h... (cached) yes
Checking whether backtrace is declared... (cached) yes
Checking whether backtrace_symbols is declared... (cached) yes
Checking for C library pcap... (cached) no
Checking for C library wpcap... (cached) no
Checking for __sync_fetch_and_add ...(cached) yes
Checking if alignment is important ...(cached) yes
Checking for inline __builtin_bswap32 ...(cached) yes
Checking for inline __builtin_bswap64 ...(cached) yes
Checking if system is big endian (for snappy) ...(cached) no
Checking if -fstack-protector works ...(cached) yes
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/linux2/normal/client_build/mongo/client/examples/authTest.o -c -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing -ggdb -pthread -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wcast-align -Winvalid-pch -O3 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -D_SCONS -DSUPPORT_UTF8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DJS_C_STRINGS_ARE_UTF8 -DMONGO_HAVE_HEADER_UNISTD_H -DMONGO_HAVE_EXECINFO_BACKTRACE -DHAVE_SYNC_FETCH_AND_ADD -DALIGNMENT_IMPORTANT -DHAVE_BSWAP32 -DHAVE_BSWAP64 -Ibuild/linux2/normal/third_party/boost -Isrc/third_party/boost -Ibuild/linux2/normal/third_party/pcre-8.30 -Isrc/third_party/pcre-8.30 -Ibuild/linux2/normal -Isrc -Ibuild/linux2/normal/mongo -Isrc/mongo src/mongo/client/examples/authTest.cpp
In file included from src/third_party/boost/boost/bind/bind.hpp:29:0,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from src/mongo/pch.h:51,
                 from src/mongo/client/dbclient.h:30,
                 from src/mongo/client/examples/authTest.cpp:21:
src/third_party/boost/boost/bind/arg.hpp: In constructor 'boost::arg<I>::arg(const T&)':
src/third_party/boost/boost/bind/arg.hpp:37:22: warning: typedef 'T_must_be_placeholder' locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
         typedef char T_must_be_placeholder[ I == is_placeholder<T>::value? 1: -1 ];
                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/pthread.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.9/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.9/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from src/mongo/client/examples/authTest.cpp:18:
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp: At global scope:
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:23:5: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
     TIME_UTC=1
     ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:23:5: error: expected '}' before numeric constant
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:23:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
In file included from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:14:0,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/mutex.hpp:16,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:10,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp:16,
                 from src/mongo/util/goodies.h:22,
                 from src/mongo/pch.h:78,
                 from src/mongo/client/dbclient.h:30,
                 from src/mongo/client/examples/authTest.cpp:21:
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:38:13: error: 'int_fast64_t' does not name a type
     typedef int_fast64_t xtime_sec_t; //INT_FAST64_MIN <= sec <= INT_FAST64_MAX
             ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:41:13: error: 'int_fast32_t' does not name a type
     typedef int_fast32_t xtime_nsec_t; //0 <= xtime.nsec < NANOSECONDS_PER_SECOND
             ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:43:5: error: 'xtime_sec_t' does not name a type
     xtime_sec_t sec;
     ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:44:5: error: 'xtime_nsec_t' does not name a type
     xtime_nsec_t nsec;
     ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:46:14: error: expected type-specifier before 'system_time'
     operator system_time() const
              ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp: In function 'xtime get_xtime(const system_time&)':
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:64:9: error: 'struct xtime' has no member named 'sec'
     res.sec=static_cast<xtime::xtime_sec_t>(time_since_epoch.total_seconds());
         ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:64:32: error: 'xtime_sec_t' in 'struct xtime' does not name a type
     res.sec=static_cast<xtime::xtime_sec_t>(time_since_epoch.total_seconds());
                                ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:65:9: error: 'struct xtime' has no member named 'nsec'
     res.nsec=static_cast<xtime::xtime_nsec_t>(time_since_epoch.fractional_seconds()*(1000000000/time_since_epoch.ticks_per_second()));
         ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:65:33: error: 'xtime_nsec_t' in 'struct xtime' does not name a type
     res.nsec=static_cast<xtime::xtime_nsec_t>(time_since_epoch.fractional_seconds()*(1000000000/time_since_epoch.ticks_per_second()));
                                 ^
In file included from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:14:0,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/mutex.hpp:16,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:10,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp:16,
                 from src/mongo/util/goodies.h:22,
                 from src/mongo/pch.h:78,
                 from src/mongo/client/dbclient.h:30,
                 from src/mongo/client/examples/authTest.cpp:21:
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp: In function 'int xtime_get(xtime*, int)':
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:73:40: error: 'get_system_time' was not declared in this scope
         *xtp=get_xtime(get_system_time());
                                        ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:73:40: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/pthread/timespec.hpp:9:0,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:8,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp:16,
                 from src/mongo/util/goodies.h:22,
                 from src/mongo/pch.h:78,
                 from src/mongo/client/dbclient.h:30,
                 from src/mongo/client/examples/authTest.cpp:21:
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:19:24: note:   'boost::get_system_time'
     inline system_time get_system_time()
                        ^
In file included from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:14:0,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/mutex.hpp:16,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:10,
                 from src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp:16,
                 from src/mongo/util/goodies.h:22,
                 from src/mongo/pch.h:78,
                 from src/mongo/client/dbclient.h:30,
                 from src/mongo/client/examples/authTest.cpp:21:
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp: In function 'int xtime_cmp(const xtime&, const xtime&)':
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:82:13: error: 'const struct xtime' has no member named 'sec'
     if (xt1.sec == xt2.sec)
             ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:82:24: error: 'const struct xtime' has no member named 'sec'
     if (xt1.sec == xt2.sec)
                        ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:83:26: error: 'const struct xtime' has no member named 'nsec'
         return (int)(xt1.nsec - xt2.nsec);
                          ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:83:37: error: 'const struct xtime' has no member named 'nsec'
         return (int)(xt1.nsec - xt2.nsec);
                                     ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:85:21: error: 'const struct xtime' has no member named 'sec'
         return (xt1.sec > xt2.sec) ? 1 : -1;
                     ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:85:31: error: 'const struct xtime' has no member named 'sec'
         return (xt1.sec > xt2.sec) ? 1 : -1;
                               ^
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp: At global scope:
src/third_party/boost/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:88:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
 } // namespace boost
 ^
scons: *** [build/linux2/normal/client_build/mongo/client/examples/authTest.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

i have tried googling this error but i cannot find anything about it, so either i am making the wrong google search, or nobody else is having this issue.

does anyone have any ideas why i might be getting this error? is there another way to get mongo installed onto the RPi?

any help is appriciated.

Comment: It would probably be a pretty obscure error.  This is probably a tough one to solve if you can't read C++, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you check http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34484/errors-when-installing-mongodb-on-the-pi and https://github.com/RickP/mongopi ? Sounds promising.

Comment: What was wrong with sudo apt-get install mongodb?

Comment: apt-get install mongoldb seems to be working... thanks. i though it wasn't in the repo, especially because the official mongo site didn't seem to supply any version compatible with the RPi on their site.

Comment: @X0r0N If you do an apt-cache search mongodb you'll see threre are a lot of packages which support mongo.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this problem?

Comment: unfortunately not. i ended up using Joan's "sudo apt-get install mongodb" solution because it wouldn't compile from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### MongoDB Is In The Repositories

You just need to install MongoDB, right?
It is already compiled and available in the Raspbian repositories:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-cache search mongodb
...
mongodb - object/document-oriented database (metapackage)
mongodb-clients - object/document-oriented database (client apps)
mongodb-dev - object/document-oriented database (development)
mongodb-server - object/document-oriented database (server package)
...
```

Is this the version you need?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-cache show mongodb-server
Package: mongodb-server
Source: mongodb
Version: 1:2.4.10-5
Architecture: armhf
Maintainer: Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) <gcs@debian.org>
Installed-Size: 13195
Depends: adduser, mongodb-clients, init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~), libboost-filesystem1.55.0, libboost-program-options1.55.0, libboost-system1.55.0, libboost-thread1.55.0, libc6 (>= 2.4), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.4.0), libpcre3 (>= 1:8.35), libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7), libsnappy1, libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0), libstdc++6 (>= 4.9), libv8-3.14.5
Replaces: mongodb (<= 1:1.4.2-2)
Homepage: http://www.mongodb.org
Priority: optional
Section: database
Filename: pool/main/m/mongodb/mongodb-server_2.4.10-5_armhf.deb
Size: 3249874
SHA256: 9e8eb3c5efc5300f78e311d7a14fe7d18ae278bf369907840f8c79f554165e22
SHA1: af8957899c73c270a9355074c25c9f4732b243ce
MD5sum: 506a5cb5e033d127ff526bfec138d4e2
Description: object/document-oriented database (server package)
 MongoDB is a high-performance, open source, schema-free
 document-oriented data store that's easy to deploy, manage
 and use. It's network accessible, written in C++ and offers
 the following features:
 .
    * Collection oriented storage - easy storage of object-style data
    * Full index support, including on inner objects
    * Query profiling
    * Replication and fail-over support
    * Efficient storage of binary data including large objects (e.g. videos)
    * Auto-sharding for cloud-level scalability
 .
 High performance, scalability, and reasonable depth of
 functionality are the goals for the project.
 .
 This package contains the server itself  (mongod) and the sharding
 server/load-balancer (mongos).
Description-md5: 98d13f2d6bef8dfdd52809bf47c48138
```

All you gotta do is install it:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this guide - http://andyfelong.com/2015/02/mongodb-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/
Worked for me flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is with the Boost Libraries. The error is specifying that struct members don't exist, which is usually an indicator that something is using the wrong version.

I would suggest making sure you're using the correct version of gcc, and that whatever configuration you've done matches the RPi.