# How to install fresh Raspbian Jessie on Raspberry Pi 1B

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

I want to install Raspbian Jessie on a clean SD card. At the moment, the only way I've found is to install Wheezy using https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst and then upgrade it to Jessie using [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27858/upgrade-to-raspbian-jessie) way.

Is there a simpler way (without upgrade)?

Comment: You can upgrade Wheezy, then save the image to your drive, and have a Jessie ready image for your next burn. I dont think there is a Jessie image officially available yet.

Comment: @ppumkin, I'm using network installer, so I don't plan to use Raspbian images at all. But it definitely could simplify the installation process for more than one installation of the same version of Jessie.

Comment: Yea... that is what I did, because it got tired of downlaoding, upgrading this and that, it took ages. I just dump the most recent image I like, Wheezy or Jessie and then burn in minutes its up and going. There is some manual post resizing involved though using ext2fs if you got Linux desktop or some convoluted way doing it in Windows with dodgy ext2fs and file chopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release v1.0.8 of raspbian-ua-netinst now installs jessie by default.
But with earlier versions you could do that by specifying `release=jessie` in `installer-config.txt`.
See https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst#installer-customization for details

Comment: For older version there was a problem with hardcoded wheezy repository for raspberrypi.org (https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/commit/3e5323a3726f1b94a75499de139bd65562f2c8ea) Does it now use jessie too?

Comment: Yes, see https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/commit/1dfa5f2b338e14df7d84b19bbcf278d0be1b48bc

Comment: And does raspberrypi.org jessie repository really work?)

Comment: I have no reason to believe it doesn't, but as I hardly ever use that repo, I can't fully attest to it either.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

Greetings from 2016!
The Foundation now offers Raspbian Jessie for download and it works on the RPi1B!

1. Download Raspbian Jessie or Raspbian Jessie Lite from the [Raspberry Pi Foundation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).
2. Follow the [official guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md) for copying the image onto an sdcard.
3. Plug the sdcard into your RPi1B.
4. Plug in the power cable.

Tested with my old Raspberry Pi 1 B.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

That link has RasPi Jessie, I don't know if it'll work with the non-Pi2s, but you can try it out. It doesn't say on the page.

Comment: Single image for both 1 & 2

Comment: That's what I though. Cheers!

Comment: @Shojan, I don't like prebuilt images but it seems to be the only way to get Jessie without upgrade at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I seem to have had a 70% success rate with installing Wheezy.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry this answer only works for RPi 2. The problem with the RPi 1s is that Debian does not support this architecture by default (ARMv6). So you need to wait for a project or someone to do the build for you.

The following answer only applies to RPi2.

Collabora provides Debian 8 Jessie images for the RPi. They claim it's the official Debian 8 Jessie for armhf architecture but with the Raspberry Pi custom kernel and recompile by them.

The instructions and download links are here: http://sjoerd.luon.net/posts/2015/02/debian-jessie-on-rpi2/

Or check directly [Collabora Blog](https://www.collabora.com/about-us/blog/) for more recent news if any.

Comment: Yep, I know that Debian does not officially support ARMv6, but Raspbian does. So my question was addressed to Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Yes I saw it just after posted. Hence the edit and forewarning. Sorry, I can't help you. Even though I have a RPi2, I did install Raspbian and then upgraded. But I guess Raspbian should explain the steps to build yourself an image. Apply those steps but use Jessie as a source. Not that using Cygwin or MinGW, you should even be able to do cross-compilation on Windows.