# NFS mount at boot with autofs on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: mount, raspbian-jessie, nfs, systemd

I'm trying to configure my RPi to use `autofs` to mount **at boot** a NFS share from my QNAP NAS.

The manual mount with

`mount -v -t nfs server://share /mnt/share`

works and also the `autofs` service works if I **manually start it** with

`sudo service autofs start`

**after** starting also `rpcbind` and `nfs-common` services first.

Now I want that all the 3 services involved (`rpcbind`, `nfs-common` and `autofs`) start automatically at boot.

Since Raspbian Jessie uses `systemd`, what should I do to add to the boot the `rpcbind` and `nfs-common` services, that should start **before** `autofs`?

Should I use `init.d` and so

`sudo update-rc.d rpcbind enable`

`sudo update-rc.d nfs-common enable`

or do I have to create a `systemd` unit file?

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded from Wheezy to Jessie and found that nfs wasn't mounting anymore.

I use mounting by editing fstab directly. This might not be an exact answer to your question, but it might fix your issue.

I've added the bold text to my existing mount entry.

> 192.168.123.123:/mnt/ext/some/dir /home/pi/for/example nfs4 _netdev,**noauto,x-systemd.automount**  0  0

This should make your disk mount at boot time.

Comment: I used `fstab` too on Wheezy. But now I want to switch to `autofs` that is more robust and reliable. Anyway fstab works too on Jessie. Did you make a clean Jessie installation or did you make an upgrade?

Comment: I did an upgrade, doing an upgrade with the old settings made the bootup wait 1min and 30sec for the nfs to be mounted, but it never succeeded, until after I changed the line.

Comment: As reported [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/41730/7732), upgrade from Wheezy to Jessie is **discouraged**. Anyway, there's an official upgrade procedure that is not guarantee to always work.

Comment: I am aware of that, to me it was worth the risk of upgrading rather than reflashing the sd card. There is nothing imporant on this Pi other than lots of configs. So since I didn't want to do all the configs over, I decided the risk was worth it :)