# Problems getting df to update on my raspberry pi

Tags: sudo, update

I am a relative newbie to this however I have a couple of raspberry pi's (with the standard out of the box configuration) and was writing a PHP that linked to a df shell command. However I found that the identical command worked on one PI and not the other. On further investigation I discovered that both df's are doing what they should, however the two versions are different - according to the respective man pages, one has a (GNU coreutils 8.23 March 2015) and the other has (GNU coreutils 8.12.197-032bb September 2011). I have tried sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade but I can't seem to get the older version of df to update to a newer version. Any suggestions as to how I can force the older df to update?

Thank you !!!

Comment: What "standard out of the box configuration"? How did you create the SD Cards and what OS? Paste output of `cat /etc/os-release` into your question.

Comment: So this is the newer version...PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

Comment: And this is the older version...PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs" So it looks like this is the problem, so is it possible to upgrade version 7 to version 8 without wiping the card etc? I am assuming the apt-get update and upgrade do not serve this function.

Comment: The cards came pre-loaded with the PI2s, so I then simply ran the updating etc before doing anything with them...

Comment: So what else can I tell you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Different Raspbian Releases

Raspbian 8 Jessie closely follows Debian 8 Jessie.
As of this writing, the [current version of `coreutils` on Debian 8 Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/coreutils) is `8.23-4`

Raspbian 7 Wheezy closely follows Debian 7 Wheezy.
As of this writing, the [current version of `coreutils` on Debian 7 Wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/coreutils) is `8.13-3.5`

The Pi running `coreutils 8.12.197-032bb` is probably still on Raspbian 7 Wheezy.
You will need to [upgrade to Raspbian 8 Jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/41730/46007) if you want to install the newer version of `coreutils`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Pi are running different releases. `Wheezy` is no longer available and not supported (apart from possible security updates).

It is not possible to update from `Wheezy` to `Jessie`. You have to do a clean install, although you could just duplicate your `Jessie` SD Card.

Comment: "It is not possible ..." is not correct. It is possible, though not recommended and therefore not well-tested.