# How to insert RPi 2 microSD card into RPi 3 without upgrading to Jessie?

Tags: sd-card, raspbian-jessie, raspbian-wheezy, update

I've got an RPi 2 B+, which has Raspbian Wheezy installed on it. Now, I have bought an RPi 3 B. I want to take the microSD card from RPi 2 B+ and insert it into RPi 3, as it is, without having to upgrade to Raspbian Jessie. I mean, updating the kernels, modules, etc. are OK. But I want to keep the wheezy and the applications installed as they are.

Is it possible to insert the microSD card from RPi 2 B+ to RPi 3 !?

***What should I do for it to work with RPi 3, without having to upgrade to Raspbian Jessie !?***

Answer (score 2):

1. Update the system to Jessie
2. Insert SD card into Pi 3

Upgrading shouldn't touch any installed stuff on your SD card. If `updating the kernels, modules, etc. are OK`, I'm sure you'll be okay with Jessie. It's because if you do that, you're pretty much upgrading to Jessie.

Secondly, there is no ARMv8 kernel on Wheezy.

In short, you really have to upgrade.

Look on the bright side. Your software gets updated, bugs eliminated. It makes everything quicker and lets you be a faster clicker. I'm not sure why you don't want to upgrade.

---

If you're really worried, **make an image of your SD card first** (hopefully not with a camera). Then,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo rpi-update
sudo reboot
```

to <s>upgrade to Jessie</s> update your software.

Instructions to update to Jessie can be found on [this answer (link)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27859/24224).

Comment: Thanks @PandaLion98 for your answer. But I'm using some stuff like `rc.local` which has been totally changed in Jessie; so my applications and codes won't work properly if I update to Jessie (As I tested with a clean installation of Jessie!).

Comment: @Omid1989 Try adding a delay on your `rc.local`. Maybe add `sleep 15` right before your command.

Comment: But I want a very fast boot @PandaLion98 .

Comment: `rc.local` has not "totally changed" in jessie.  Your solution to your problem here is **totally absurd**.  Seriously.  Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: It is irresponsible to recommend inexperienced users run `rpi-update`. This updates firmware but the software is not fully tested, and there are a number of outstanding issues with the 4.4 kernel. Also you can NOT upgrade to Jessie this way. There are unsupported (convoluted) upgrade methods, but these are not for those without significant Linux experience.

Comment: @Milliways Noted. I did recommend making an image first.