# Insert RPi 2 microSD card into RPi 3. How?

Tags: sd-card, raspbian-jessie, raspbian-wheezy, update

I have an RPi 2 B+, which had previously wheezy installed on it. I used the following articles to upgrade to jessie:

[Upgrade to Raspbian Jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27858/upgrade-to-raspbian-jessie)

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121880

It has been successfully updated to jessie, and works without problem.

Now I have bought an RPi 3. I want to take the microSD card from my RPi 2 B+, and insert it to RPi 3.

***Is it OK!? Will it work?***

***Is there anything to do before or after inserting the microSD card into RPi 3!?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DO NOT run `rpi-update` 
>   It is unnecessary and can install untested software, although in this case (just after an upgrade) it probably won't hurt.

Yes it will work. Just simple insert your card to the RPi3 and boot. After boot perform once more:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks @Huczu for your quick answer. Is the `rpi-update` command a supported command? Is it needed?

Comment: @Omid1989 DO NOT run rpi-update https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=835914#p835914