# Proper way to upgrade tmux to latest version?

Tags: raspbian

Running raspian and trying to upgrade tmux, it seems like the latest version in the official repo is 1.6

```
$ apt-cache policy tmux
tmux:
  Installed: 1.6-2
  Candidate: 1.6-2
  Version table:
 *** 1.6-2 0
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

What are the options here? Is there an alternative repo I could pull from?

I started looking into building from source here
 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/README. Seems like I would have to install libevent and ncurses as well, already it is a bit overwhelming.

Comment: If you want something approaching the latest you will need to build it from source. it is not that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you want to selectively upgrade tmux when you are using the old wheezy distribution.

Presumably you have good reasons to still be on wheezy.  The version of tmux is the most appropriate for that distribution.

I am using the current stable distribution jessie.

```
$ apt-cache policy tmux
tmux:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9-6
  Version table:
     1.9-6 0
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't realize that I was behind :-) I'm upgrading now based off of this thread - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27858/upgrade-to-raspbian-jessie

Comment: So far so good, and checking the version post-update says I have tmux 1.9