# How to upgrade from an old Raspbian version on a Pi without a computer?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, software-installation, update

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B, with Wheezy installed. Running some commands tells me version `7.11.x` is installed. I would like to upgrade to Raspbian Jessie, which is on `8.8`, if I'm not mistaken.

One way is to go to raspberrypi.org and download the latest image, but I don't have a micro SD card reader. Is there any way I can download it and upgrade it directly on my Pi?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27858/upgrade-to-raspbian-jessie (stackexchange) ... simply search for upgrame raspbian wheezy to jessie and you will see a lot of help on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

As per this [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121880) on the Raspberry Pi Forum:

1. Modify the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` by running `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`. Change `wheezy` to `jessie` in the first line, so it reads `deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi`
2. Modify the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` by running `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`. change `wheezy` to `jessie` in the first line and add `ui` to the end of that line. The line should read `deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian jessie main ui`
3. Create the directory `/home/pi/.config/autostart` by running `mkdir /home/pi/.config/autostart` in the terminal. (Note the `.` in front of `config`.)
4. Run `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal to update the `apt` index files.
5. Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to start the upgrade process. This will take a couple of hours. Whenever prompted to update a file during this process, choose the `Y` option to accept the new file; if you don't want to be bothered with these prompts, then call `apt-get` with the `-y` option using `sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade`.

On first boot of Jessie you will see messages about:

```
Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
```

Wait until the messages stop then login as the user pi. You may need to run `start x` to get the GUI to load up. This screen might go black as it loads the GUI this is fine.

When the GUI has loaded you can install all the new software packages by running:

```
sudo apt-get install rc-gui libreoffice libreoffice-gtk alacarte bluej greenfoot claws-mail
```

This will install the new GUI version of raspi-config, LibreOffice and its GTK extension, the Alacarte menu editor, the BlueJ and Greenfoot Java IDEs and the ClawsMail email client.

The GUI will need cleaning up:

1. To load the new version of the PiX GTK theme. (Note the . in front of themes) run ``
2. To prevent the ClipIt application from automatically starting on boot run `sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/clipit-startup.desktop`
3. To prevent the Wicd network manager from automatically starting on boot run `sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/wicd-tray.desktop`
4. To remove the huge list of application shortcuts in the “Other” menu run `sudo rm –rf /var/lib/menu-xdg`
5. To select to boot to desktop with autologin as the pi user run `sudo raspi-config nonint do_boot_behaviour_new B4`
6. To hide the menu shortcut to the Openbox window manager, whose functionality has been replaced by the Appearance Settings preferences application run `sudo rm /usr/share/applications/obconf.desktop`

If possible I would strongly recommend a clean install of Jessie, it's probably going to be less hassle then running all of these commands. **Definitely backup anything important before you attempt the upgrade**.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative (because the above procedure will take a wee bit of time), connect a USB-multicard reader/writer to your Pi, and flash a freshly downloaded Jessie to it. The Pi1+2 supply at most 100mA on USB IIRC, which is enough.

The latest image can be found here: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest

Try:
`wget -qO - https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest | zcat -dfc | dd bs=1M of=/dev/sda`,
assuming that your new microsd card is sda. Check with `fdisk -l`, and of course
make some backup elsewhere with `rsync -avuP ... ...`

If you have not made enormous changes outside ~pi, you can just copy your home folder to the new card before booting it and expanding it.